# How to convert eregi to preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

I am using a lib which uses

```
eregi($match="^http/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+[ \t]+([0-9]+)[ \t]*(.*)\$",$line,$matches)
```

but as eregi is deprecated now, i want to convert above to preg_match. I tried it as below

```
preg_match($match="/^http/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+[ \t]+([0-9]+)[ \t]*(.*)\$/i",$line,$matches)
```

but it throws an error saying `Unknown modifier '[' in` filename.php

any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You can leave out the `$match=` in both code examples, that way they are completely unnecessary

Comment: ["How to change PHP's eregi to preg_match"](http://customphpfunctions.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-change-phps-eregi-to-pregmatch.html) has an explanation of both eregi and preg_match and also how to replace the depreciated function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `/` as the regex delimiter (ie. `preg_match('/.../i', ...)`), you need to escape any instances of `/` in your pattern or php will think it's referring to the end of the pattern.

You can also use a different character such as `%` as your delimiter:

```
preg_match('%^http/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+[ \t]+([0-9]+)[ \t]*(.*)$%i',$line,$matches)
```

Comment: +1 for `/` explaining. Yes when PHP finds any `/` in your regular expression, it will consider as the end of the regular expression.

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape the [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) inside the regular expression (in this case the `/`):

```
"/^http\\/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+[ \t]+([0-9]+)[ \t]*(.*)\$/i"
```

But you could also chose a different delimiter like `~`:

```
"~^http/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+[ \t]+([0-9]+)[ \t]*(.*)\$~i"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
preg_match("@^http/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+[ \t]+([0-9]+)[ \t]*(.*)\$@i",$line,$matches)
```

- You can drop the the `$match=`
- You are using `/` as the delimiter
  and there is another / present in the
  regex after `http`, which effectively
  marks the end of your regex. When PHP
  sees the `[` after this it complains.
- You can use a different set of
  delimiters as `@` or escape the `/` after `http`